# Why is $P(X>m+n) = P(X>m)\cdot P(X>n)$?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

$P$ is probability, $X$ is a random variable, $m$, $n$ are two scalars. I know that $P(X>m+n)$ is not $P(X>m\cap X>n)$, and think that this does make some sense. I just need some more detailed explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain how you know that $P(x>m+x)$ is not $P(X>m \cap X>n)?$  If you cannot explain why, then you really can't claim to "know" or understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not generally true, *unless* you are dealing with a memoryless distribution (such as geometric or exponential), and so for positive $m,n$: $$\mathsf P(X>m+n\mid X>m)=\mathsf P(X>n)$$

Thus, since for positive $m,n$ it follows that $X>m+n$ entails $X>m$. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>m+n) &=\mathsf P(X>m \cap X>m+n)\\&~~\vdots\\&=\mathsf P(X>m)\mathsf P(X>n)\end{align}$$

Comment: P(X > m ∩ X > m + n) = P(X > m + n | X > m) * P(X > m) = P(X > n) * P(X > m)? Thank you very much.